# 5 cars, 4 parking places. Derangements and permutations with fixed points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, derangements

I found an exercise in combinatorics:

> In the parking of a building, there a re five parking spots, with their owner cars assigned
>   to them. One day only four cars arrived. In how many ways can they park so that not one cars 
>   parks on their corresponding spot?

So I think the following way: consider the missing car. It may arrive and park on its own parking spot, there are $5\cdot D_4$ ways of doing that, where $D_n$ is the number of derangements of $n$-element set, or it may arrive and find that his place is already taken. Then it takes someone other's place, thus making a complete derangement of 5 element set. So the total number is $5\cdot D_4+D_5$. Am I thinking correctly?

The real problem I have with this is that I found it in some early pop-quiz some teacher gave during the introduction to probability class. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Emulate the problem using 5 pages and 5 trash bins.

Comment: Depending on how you read the problem, you may want to replace $5D_4$ with $D_4$, since the four cars have already been chosen.

Comment: yes, vadimir123 I was switching between these two options. I just ran a simulation in mathematica, and it works like I wrote; after all, any car could be the missing one. hjpotter92 I don't exactly understand how would that help.

Comment: The simulation will simulate what you tell it to simulate.  If the question stipulates that cars A,B,C,D are here and car E is not, then you should have $D_4$.  If the question asks how many ways there are for *some* four out of five cards to arrive, then you should have $5D_4$.  The way you wrote it I'm inclined toward the former.

Comment: Okay, forget about whether it's 5, or not. The problem is, it involves using $D_n$. I am fairly certain that the students in that class did not had derangements in curriculum. So, any ideas if there is any simpler explanation?

Comment: The more general problem of counting injections without fixed points is discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367686/how-many-injective-functions-f1-m-to1-n-has-no-fixed-point-m

Answer (score 1):

The four employee cars can either leave the chief's place free and park falsely in $D_4=9$ ways, or they use the chief's place, and then the chief coming later would also be in a false place. This can happen in $D_5=44$ ways. It follows that there are $53$ ways for the four cars to park falsely.

Answer (score 0):

Lets split into cases depending on which parking spot is open after the four cars have parked.  Number the cars $1-5$ and suppose car $5$ is the one that didn't show up.

Case $1$: Parking spot $5$ is left empty.

In this case there are $D_4=9$ ways for the four cars to park in the other four spots.

Case $2$: Parking spot $1$ is left empty.

Here, if car $1$ parks in spot $5$, then the other three cars fill in with $D_3=2$ ways.  If car $1$ parks in any of the other three spots, you can check that there are $3$ ways cars $2-4$ can fill in, making $9$ total.  For this case, there are $2+9=11$ ways for the cars to park.

Since parking spots $2-4$ are the same as parking spot $1$ by symmetry, we get $11$ ways for each of those cases too.  Altogether we find $9+4\cdot11=\boxed{53}$ ways for the cars to park.