# How does the OEIS-A076731 figure out?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

This sequence can be defined by the follow recursion which is written by the Mathematica format :

```
f[n_,k_] := Which[k==0, 1, k>0, (k-1) f[n-2,k-2]+(n-1) f[n-1,k-1], True, 0];
```

And the OEIS gives me this formula :

$$f(n,k)=\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}
(-1)^i(n-i)!\binom{k}{i}$$

But I do not know how to get this formula from the recursion.

Related question :[How many injective functions $f:[1,...,m]\to{[1,...,n]}$ has no fixed point? $(m\le n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367686/how-many-injective-functions-f1-m-to1-n-has-no-fixed-point-m)

Comment: @Shahab I had read that question before I asked .However , the question is just about the introduction and the result of this sequence while I want to know the process .

Comment: @OriBeta: In that case, it would have made sense to link to that question yourself.

Comment: @joriki As a non-English-speaker , I don't understand you exactly .Do you mean I need to edit this question to add  the link ?

Comment: @OriBeta: I mean that, since you had read that other question and noticed the connection, it would have been a good idea to link to that question from this question, to allow readers of your question to profit from the information available there. Yes, I'd still put the link in the question, both to link to it and also to clarify that you don't consider this a duplicate.

Comment: @joriki Okay , I have done that . Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the fixed point $F$, in which place we can view it an injection $[m]\setminus F\to [n] \setminus F$. By counting the fixed point, we have 
$$\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{i}f(m-i,n-i)=\binom{n}{m}m!$$
Let $k=n-m$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{m-i}f(m-i,m+k-i)
=\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{j}f(j,k+j)
=\binom{m+k}{m}m!$$
Then
$$f(m,k+m)=\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{m-i}\binom{m}{i}\binom{i+k}{i}i!$$
By the lemma below. That is
$$f(m,n)=\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{m-i}\binom{m}{i}\binom{i+n-m}{i}i!
=\frac{1}{(n-m)!}\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i}\binom{m}{j}(n-j)!$$

Lemma. For two sequences $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$, then
$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}b_i\iff b_n=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}a_i$$ 
Pf. We can compute that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k+m}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m}
=\binom{n}{m}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k-m}\binom{n-i}{k-m}
=\delta_{nm}$$